# Alignment of custom item symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, itemize

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item[$\Rightarrow$] a
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like the rightarrow has there left side align with the left side of the triangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item[$\Rightarrow$\hskip-0.15cm] a
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Not so hacky:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{%
    \makebox[\widthof{$\Rightarrow$}][c]{%
        \scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}%
        \hfill%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item[$\Rightarrow$] a
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: think, it is work in a real use, if I do some little modification.

Answer (score 4):

What about this solution?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace{4.6pt}] a
\item[\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace{4.6pt}] a
\item[\(\Rightarrow\)] a
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The default itemize symbol is in `\scriptsize`, in case you want to be consistent with other itemizations in the presentation.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter! I've corrected my answer according to your suggestion and also modified it adding only a little space after the itemize symbol instead of the phantom (it is more precise this way, even if it is similar to your first solution).

Comment: I prefer the first solution, which don't force to modify all \item entry.

Comment: @Maïeul Don't worry, you have already accepted samcarter's solution, that shows your preference. My answer is only a possible alternative, maybe someone else could find mine useful! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Please feel free to roll back the edit in case you don't like it.

Comment: @samcarter I like it, it is more elegant!